# Looking for intermediate proxy reading a proxy.pac

Tags: proxy, http-proxy, web-proxy

I have a setup where I need a corporate upstream proxy, as well as several differnt proxies that are set up as SSH Socks proxies.

In the past I used px on the windows host machine to parse a self-made proxy.pac (which then depending on the host uses either the corporate proxy or a suitable local proxy via ssh).

Unfortunately they introduced a new security solution that blocks px somehow. Tried to build px as a docker image but it appears to me that px is 100% intended to be run on windows, so it looks like I cannot build it on linux (VM or docker image).

Do you know about any other proxy alternative which I can configure to read a proxy.pac and forward a web request according to this proxy.pac?

This way I could just set the http_proxy variables to this service and let it decide on the upstream instead of changing http_proxy over and over manually.

Answer (score 0):

Px now supports Linux though PAC support is still pending.

The Windows binary is now built with Nuitka so it might fare better with anti-virus tools that didn't like the older PyInstaller binary.

If that doesn't work, you can still install Px as a Python module - `pip install px-proxy` and that should work since it's unlikely they will block the Python binary.